# SOAP WSS4JInInterceptor Security processing failed (actions mismatch)

Tags: soap, wss4j

I have been struggling, for several days trying to get a simple SOAP request to pass WS-Security, after many emails I was finally able to get some logs out of the service provider...

Note that the webservice is SOAP 1.2

```
2021-04-11 23:49:24,052:INFO :ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-5:ptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor:class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternalapplication/soap+xml
2021-04-11 23:49:47,867:WARN :ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-28:urity.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor:Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
2021-04-11 23:49:47,867:WARN :ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-28:xf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain:Interceptor for {http://[redacted]/rti/cdd/wsdl}CDDService has thrown exception, unwinding now
```

Sadly this hasn't helped much as in searching for this error it appears to be quite ambiguous, one of which mentioning a bug in the WSS4JInInterceptor where whitespace between the body open tag, and the first node can cause this, however even in removing that whitespace, I still receive the same error.

Here is the XML I'm sending (using `Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8;action="mySoapAction"` header), the service provider has confirmed they are receiving the XML body in full:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sch="http://[redacted]/rti/cdd/schema" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1618447264">
                <wsse:Username>[redacted]</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-tokenprofile-1.0#PasswordText">[redacted]</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sch:cddRequest clientID="1213" clientCandidateId="3">
            <candidateName>
                <firstName>Learner</firstName>
                <lastName>Learner</lastName>
            </candidateName>
            <webAccountInfo>
                <email>learner@nowhere.com</email>
            </webAccountInfo>
            <lastUpdate>2021/04/15 00:47:44 BST</lastUpdate>
            <primaryAddress>
                <addressType>Home</addressType>
                <address1>[redacted]</address1>
                <address2>[redacted]</address2>
                <city>Gold Coast</city>
                <postalCode>4218</postalCode>
                <country>AU</country>
                <phone>
                    <phoneNumber>[redacted]</phoneNumber>
                    <phoneCountryCode>[redacted]</phoneCountryCode>
                </phone>
            </primaryAddress>
            <candidatePrefs>
                <candidatePref prefType="ConfirmationPreference">
                    <prefOption>email</prefOption>
                </candidatePref>
                <candidatePref prefType="ReminderPreference">
                    <prefOption>email</prefOption>
                </candidatePref>
                <candidatePref prefType="LocalePreference">
                    <prefOption>en_GB</prefOption>
                </candidatePref>
            </candidatePrefs>
        </sch:cddRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged the question WSS4J but by any chance have you written the security header by hand? Because all your namespaces are wrong:

```
wsse = http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
wsu = http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
Type attribute = http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-tokenprofile-1.0#PasswordText
```

Pay attention to the dashes (`-`).

Correct namespaces are:

```
wsse = http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
wsu = http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd        
Type attribute = http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText
```